# SQL - Primary Key, Clustered Index, Auto-increment

Tags: mysql, sql

My website displays posts by DATE even though the SQL table is ordered by ID. Since the order of the ID is not always the same as the order of the DATE, I run the query with `ORDER BY 'DATE'`.

**SQL Table Example:**

```
----------------------------
| ID | DATE                |
----------------------------
| 1  | 2011-10-20 00:00:00 | 
| 2  | 2012-10-20 00:00:00 |
| 3  | 2010-10-20 00:00:00 |
| 4  | 2011-09-20 00:00:00 |
----------------------------

To query I use: SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY 'DATE';
```

My questions:

1. **Would it benefit the query performance if the cluster index or primary key of the table was the DATE column?**
2. **Is it possible to have the ID column auto-increment when it is not the primary key?**

What I want to do is make the query as fast as possible (which I think would be possible by making the DATE the cluster index or primary key) but also allow each post to have a unique auto-increment ID. I tried to make DATE the primary key but I got an error saying "there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key".

Comment: `ORDER BY 'DATE'` will not order your result, because that sorts by the constant string literal DATE, not by the value of the column DATE. As you are using a reserved word for the column name you need to quote it using `"` or backticks (the way you did with `table`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not define the date as a primary key, but rather add an index on the field. Unique, if needed. I believe it is possible to have an autoincrement on a non primary key field, but trying it yourself will give you the best answer!

<-- EDIT -->

To answer your comment question, I can't say its a BAD idea, but dates are always picky. For once, you have to decide if you use UTC or local date, preview how daylight saving time affects your program, foresee if the need of a date update would be possible at some time of the application life, and things like that. I rather forget about that and just go with the unique autogenerated key.
If you do go for the date as PK, you can use timestamp and avoid the second sequence column.

I found more info about dates as primary keys at [techtarget.com](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Using-date-as-a-primary-key) and [made2mentor.com](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/05/date-vs-integer-datatypes-as-primary-key-for-date-dimensions/).

Comment: So it's a bad idea to make the date my clustered index?

Comment: @supercoolville I added my answer on the post as an edit because it was too long :)

Answer (score 0):

It is nice for indexes if the values going into it are unordered. Not mandatory but nice. Since they are trees if an index is only an autoincrement column you end up with an unbalanced tree right from the beginning each time you rebulid the index you are guaranteed to always get unbalanced as new data gets added because it will only get added to one leaf of the tree (until the index page is full).

For the clustered indexes on auto increment fields (which primary keys are by default in Sybase, MS SQL and probably everything else) it is probably a good idea to do relatively frequent index rebuilds. My philosophy is to cluster on the most common scan. So I might set my primary key to the ID column but I'd cluster on the DATE so when I do things like select Date from table where  or select ... order by Date the query will scan consecutive items in as it reads the pages off disk.